# Help me understand a proof that the transformation of a multidimensional Uniform RV is also uniformly distributed

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, change-of-variable, jacobian

I've had this exercise and my approach was completely different from the official solution and I am not exactly following the official solutions proof. I understand how they get there, but not the conclusion.
How does this show the transformation is also uniform random variable?

The exercise:
Let z be a uniform D-Dimensional RV $u ∼ p_u(u) = Unif(0, 1)$.
We consider a transformation
$$
f(u) = x
$$
Where
$$
\mathbf{x} = 
\begin{bmatrix}
x_{1:d} \\
x_{d+1:D}\\
\end{bmatrix} =
\begin{bmatrix}
u_{1:d} \\
u_{d+1:D} + A(u_{1:d})\\
\end{bmatrix}
$$

The first part considers $A$ to be a linear transformation.
So, $f^{-1}(x) = u$
$$\begin{align}
& u_{1:d} = x_{1:d} \\ 
& u_{d+1:D} = x_{d+1:D} - Ax_{1:d}
\end{align}
$$

We go on to find the Jacobian of the inverse function above

$$
\begin{bmatrix}I_d & 0\\-A & I{D-d}\end{bmatrix}
$$

We conclude that the determinant of the Jacobian = 1 for an arbitrary sample $\tilde{x}$.
And $$ p_x({\tilde{x}}) = p_z({f^{-1}\tilde{x}})\cdot |det\frac{\partial f^{-1}(\tilde{x})}{\partial x} | = q(f^{-1}(\tilde{x})) = 1.
$$

It says that we use the fact that $\tilde{z} = f^{-1}(x) \in [0,1]^D$.
Therefore,
$q(\tilde{z}) = 1$.

The next part proving that for arbitrarily complex functions $A$, $x$ is still distributed uniformly because the Jacobian determinant doesn't change.

You help in understanding this is much appreciated.
If someone can format the matrix and vectors correctly I am grateful as well.

Comment: What part is confusing you ? Also I think that $A$ is a function of the first $d$ elements of $u$ right ?

Comment: @P.Quinton Yes, Thank you! A is afunction of the first d elements, I am sorry, I made it clearer.
The Conclusion mainly, I don't quite get for one why the q(z) = 1 and how this shows that x has a uniform distribution.
I would have written them out and try to show that the probabilities of each of the elements is constant.

Comment: @P.Quinton Did you have an idea or explanation of how the conclusion came that $q(z) = 1$, I guess since it's arbitrary this proves that it's uniform.

Comment: Well, $q$ isn’t defined in your question so it is hard to tell, but my guess is that it is $p_z$, and therefore $1$ on the appropriate range.

Comment: @P.Quinton Thanks! Indeed it isn't defined in the exercise, I presume they just have $q$ because it's common practice and were careless. If it were $p(z)$ than this is kind of a roundabout way. Wouldn't it be valid to just use the Universality of the uniform?